# Ajax error when renaming a file with php, still gets renamed

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, rename

Im trying to rename files through a website on my webserver (RasPi) . This all goes through an jquery ajax request and it works. the files get renamed successfully but for some reason i'm getting an error in my browser console. [image]

When i try to rename files from a webbrowser on the pi, it works without any errors appearing.

JS Part

```
$.ajax({
url: 'rsrc/php/filemanager.php',
type: 'get',
data: {'action': 'renameFile', 'path': $folderpath, 'oldfilename': $oldfilename, 'newfilename': $newfilename},
success: function(answer) {
  console.log(answer);
  if(answer == "OK") {
    location.reload();
  }
},
error: function(xhr, desc, err) {
  console.log(xhr);
  console.log("Details: " + desc + "\nError: " + err);
}
});
```

PHP

```
    if ($_GET['action'] == 'renameFile') {
      $subfolderPath = $_GET['path'];

      $oldfilename = $_GET['oldfilename'];
      $newfilename = $_GET['newfilename'];

      $preview_oldfilename = substr($oldfilename, 0, strrpos($oldfilename, ".")) . ".jpg";
      $preview_newfilename = substr($newfilename, 0, strrpos($newfilename, ".")) . ".jpg";

      $renameOldPath = $uploadfolder . $subfolderPath . $oldfilename;
      $renameNewPath = $uploadfolder . $subfolderPath . $newfilename;
  $renamePreviewOldPath = $uploadpreviewfolder . $subfolderPath . $preview_oldfilename;
  $renamePreviewNewPath = $uploadpreviewfolder . $subfolderPath . $preview_newfilename;
  echo $renameOldPath;
  //To be revisited: Empty Error
  $firstRename = rename($renameOldPath, $renameNewPath);
  $secondRename = rename($renamePreviewOldPath, $renamePreviewNewPath);

  if($firstRename == true && $secondRename == true) {
    echo "OK";
  } else {
    echo "NO";
  }
}
```

Sorry for the bad formatting here. Even if i just print the paths out and use mv manually it works just fine. I still get the same error when i use exec. Any idea what could cause this? I tried it on Chrome and Firefox so far

Comment: I can see a `readyState: 0` on your `xhr` object. The zero code means `The request is not initialized`. You can see more: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=xhr+ready+state+codes

Comment: @matze Couldn't get more complicated hum?  https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php

Comment: Can you see the network tab on your developer tools if the request is sended, and the final result and http code?

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude Its Status is marked as canceled, the size is also 0. It didnt got any response. If i try to access the php file directly `filemanager.php?action=renameFile&path=%2F&oldfilename=hello.jpg&newfilename=new.jpg` it works fine and returns OK

Comment: and btw: i also got a function to delete a file and it works without any problems. the ajax request is basically the same

Comment: I also noticed that if i comment the renaming functions out it works without problems (but doesnt rename the files)

Comment: So the server response is empty? No php errors? No HTTP 500 error code? Nothing? Your last sentence: `if I comment the renaming functions out it works`, seems to me a 500 error, or something similar. Share with us your network tab.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude with the renaming function commented out: http://i.imgur.com/dpqyC1f.png
http://i.imgur.com/939sxHX.png
http://i.imgur.com/8uEAUix.png

With the renaming function running (returning the error):
http://i.imgur.com/mNMzKNR.png
http://i.imgur.com/2QOY8tU.png
http://i.imgur.com/oFEkj4i.png

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude Nope, no errors or any kind of error codes. really just nothing. Its bugging me since yesterday and i dont really know what could cause it because most of the other functions and ajax requested i already wrote worked without any errors

Comment: I hate Chrome debugger XD you should retest your code and isolate the problem, maybe conflicts with another code. You can also rewrite the code separating the call and the promises, maybe this work. I can't see more with these details

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude tried a synchronous call in the js file, now it works, but i doubt keeping it as a synchronous call would be a good idea or?

Comment: Synchronous is that when you call to some server file, you must wait till it ends to execute the next sentence. So you should decide what is better for you. Sometimes, sync is  necessary, sometimes not.